# How to use element name in ng-show and form validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-show

I was looking at the W3school example of form validation for Angular JS, here is the code:

```
<form name="myForm">
<p>Name:
<input name="myName" ng-model="myName" required>
<span ng-show="myForm.myName.$touched && myForm.myName.$invalid">The name is required.</span>
</p>

<p>Adress:
<input name="myAddress" ng-model="myAddress" required>
<span ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$untouched">Please enter address.</span>
</p>

</form>
```

note the ng-show="myForm.myName.$touched", does Angular find the element's name attribute as default?  What if the input has an id and I want to use that instead of name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in below way..

```
<input name="myName" id="myNameId" ng-model="myName" required>
 <span ng-show='angular.element($("#myNameId")).$touched && angular.element($("#myNameId")).$invalid'>The name is required.</span>
</p>
```